# Collect input value based on button element hierarchy position

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My actual html code:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
        Informação Pessoal
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Nome</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminName" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $adminData->name; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminEmail" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $adminData->email; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="savePersInfo">Guardar Alteração</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have multiple such panels, each one with a button that has specific ID. My goal is to collect all the input within the panel that the button was pressed. Although this sounds easy, my MAIN goal is to reuse the same function on multiple pages that have multiple panels (since the structures is simillar), to then use ajax to update the information. The only thing that I would need to provide the function is the id of the button so it can find automatically the relative input.
I am trying to accomplish this in vanilla js, though im ok with jquery.

My actual js code:

```
document.getElementById('savePersInfo').onclick = function(){
var inputArray = ['adminName', 'adminEmail'];
console.log(collectInfo(inputArray));
};

function collectInfo(inputArray){
    $inputValueArray = []
    for(var c = 0; c < inputArray.length; c++){
        $inputValueArray[c] = document.querySelectorAll('[name="' + inputArray[c] + '"]')[0].value;
    }
    return $inputValueArray;
}
```

As you see here I need to specify the name of the input to be able to retrieve it, what I want is not to do that and have JS find it automatically based on the panel is was clicked on.

Any suggestions/ideas on how this can be accomplished ?

ps: ignore the inline styling and other layout stuff, early development phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either javasscript's [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) or jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), and with those find the closest element being ancestor to both the `button` and `input`'s, e.g. `panel-body`.

From there you then simply use that element as starting point, e.g. with javascript [`element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)), and select all `inputs` and grab their value.

*Note, if to use the javascript version and support IE (it doesn't know of `closest()`), you can make use of the "polyfill" I added at the end.*

***Updated** based on a comment, where I added a `checkbox` and `select` to my "javascript" code sample to show it works with those too, and how to get the button id.*

Stack snippet - javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach( function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', findInputs);
})

function findInputs() {  

  console.clear();
  
  var button_id = this.id;
  
  this.closest('.panel-body').querySelectorAll('input, select').forEach( function(inp) {
    var test_checked = ((inp.type == 'checkbox' && inp.checked) ? ' checked' : '');
    console.log(button_id, inp.value + test_checked)
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
        Informação Pessoal
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Nome</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminName" class="form-control" value="name 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminEmail" class="form-control" value="email 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Test</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="adminTest" class="form-control" value="test 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Test 2</span>
                <select name="adminTest2" class="form-control">
                  <option value="Test2-a">Test2-a</option>
                  <option selected value="Test2-b">Test2-b</option>
                  <option value="Test2-c">Test2-c</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="savePersInfo">Guardar Alteração</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Stack snippet - jQuery

```js
$('button').each( function() {
  $(this).click(findInputs);
})


function findInputs() {
  $(this).closest('.panel-body').find('input').each( function() {
    console.log( $(this).val() );
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
        Informação Pessoal
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Nome</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminName" class="form-control" value="name 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminEmail" class="form-control" value="email 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="savePersInfo">Guardar Alteração</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
        Informação Pessoal 2
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Nome</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminName" class="form-control" value="name 2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminEmail" class="form-control" value="email 2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="savePersInfo2">Guardar Alteração 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Add javascript `closest()` support for IE9+

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches)
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
                                Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;

if (!Element.prototype.closest)
    Element.prototype.closest = function(s) {
        var el = this;
        if (!document.documentElement.contains(el)) return null;
        do {
            if (el.matches(s)) return el;
            el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
        } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1); 
        return null;
    };
```

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: What if I want to pass the id of the pressed button ? Since I want to somehow distinguish them. Tested your code and it does not pick up selects, checkboxes nor radio although they are are input.

Comment: @Sashka Added a checkbox to my javascript code sample to show it works, and how to get the button id.

Comment: @Sashka And next time you might want to wait a little, before unaccept an answer, and give the answerer a chance to update their answer

Comment: @Sashka FYI, a `select` is not an `input`, sou you need to add its `select` to the selector.

Comment: I am sorry I just got confused if it should be considered as accepted or not. True about the select.

Comment: @Sashka I just now updated my answer to show it works with both checkbox and select.

Comment: @Sashka No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) on the element with the passed `id` to target the panel you are looking for. Then use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return the value of all inputs from the selected panel.

Try the following way:

```js
document.getElementById('savePersInfo').onclick = function(){
  console.log(collectInfo(this.id));
};

function collectInfo(id){
  var panel = document.getElementById(id).closest(".panel.panel-primary")
  var $inputValueArray = [...panel.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')].map(i => i.value);
  return $inputValueArray;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
        Informação Pessoal
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Nome</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminName" class="form-control" value="John Michale Kane">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="adminEmail" class="form-control" value="john@gmail.com">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="savePersInfo">Guardar Alteração</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```